# Plural or singular in coordination

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural

> A number of books were published in 2020 in the category/categories of translated and non-translated children's books.

Grammatically, should "category" be singular or plural here? "Translated" and "non-translated" are two categories - so I assume it should be plural, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, two categories are plural, since two is greater than one.

Comment: By the way, when a construction is causing puzzlement like this, it’s often a good cue to consider reworking the phrase entirely. For instance, in the case of your example, is the notion of categories necessary? Is it already present in the discourse? If no, then how about something like “A number of children’s books were published in 2020, both translated and not”?

Comment: What @PaulTanenbaum said. When in doubt, first consider rephrasing. I'm sure that's what most native Anglophones do, rather than consult textbooks or "experts".